# Grounding the table

Tags: esd

I'm preparing my private laboratory stand. I want to use an ESD mat, but my power outlet is far from the table so I can't ground it directly. I want to ground the mat on a table and I wish to use an ESD grounding plug. Can I connect it to the extension cord or it must be attached to the ground of outlet directly? Could it make any unintentional potential difference?

Comment: What is a "private laboratory stand"?

Comment: I mean a table for work. Soldering, building, repairing electronics

Comment: Why would you build this table at such a distance from a power outlet when clearly you will need local power outlets for a soldering iron and electrical equipment??

Comment: There is no possibility to put it closer. It's not up to me.

Comment: Depends on what the table has done wrong. Maybe it's okay just to restrict TV and / or smartphone usage :D

Comment: Hah, nice joke ;). But like I said, I can't remove any furnitures. It's the only place

Comment: I don't know what to envision from *private laboratory stand*.

Answer (score 7):

The table will need power, for soldering etc.

Run an extension lead from your nearest outlet to the table. Treat the ground on the extension lead as the common ground for your mat, you, solder station, oscilloscopes, signal generators.

The point about ESD safety is to have common, local, ground, that everything connects to.